# Angular Component Bindings Undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I'm trying to put together my first angular component with ngRoute and so far I'm unable to get data to resolve.
config:

```
.when('/myfirstcomponent', {
    template: '<myfirstcomponent claimKeys="$resolve.claimKeys"></myfirstcomponent>',
    resolve: {
        claimKeys: ['$http', function($http) {
            $http.get('server/claimkeys.json').then((response) => {
                var claimKeys = response.data.DATASET.TABLE;
                return claimKeys;
            });
        }]
    }
})
```

Component:

```
    .component('myfirstcomponent', {
        bindings: {
            'claimKeys': '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/component.html',
        controller: [function() {
            this.$onInit = function() {
                var vm = this;
                console.log(vm.claimKeys);
            };


        }]
```

The html for the component simply has a p element with some random text that's all.

I can see when debugging that I am retrieving data but I cannot access it on the component controller...

EDIT: Thanks to the accepted answer below I have fixed my issue. It didn't have anything to do with an issue with asynchronous calls but with how I had defined my route and the component. See below code for fix. Thanks again.

Comment: Well my first problem is in my template 'claimKeys' should be claim-keys. However that simply resolves to a string '$resolve.claimKeys'... Little progress but not getting any further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `return claimKeys` does not return anything to `$resolve.claimKeys` since it's async. See the dupe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

some issues:

- as you said *claimKeys* within directive should be *claim-keys*
- its binding should be '<' (one way binding) or '=' (two way binding), but not '@' which just passes to directive a string found between quotes
- in your directive's controller `var vm = this;` should be above
  *$onInit* function and not inside it (the scopes are different)
- `resolve.claimkeys` should return $http's promise and not just call
  it
- *claimKeys* should be received by router's controller as injection and passed to its template
- `controllerAs: '$resolve'` should be used by router

  ```
  app.component('myfirstcomponent', {
    bindings: {
      'claimKeys': '='
    },
    template: 'components/component.html',
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this;
      this.$onInit = function() {            
        console.log(vm.claimKeys);
      };
    }
  });

  app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('myfirstcomponent', {
      url: '/myfirstcomponent',
      template: '<myfirstcomponent claim-keys="$resolve.claimKeys"></myfirstcomponent>',
      resolve: {
        claimKeys: ['$http', function($http) {
          return $http.get('claimkeys.json').then((response) => {
            return response.data.DATASET.TABLE;
          });
        }]
      },
      controller: function (claimKeys) {
        this.claimKeys = claimKeys;
      },
      controllerAs: '$resolve'
    })
  });
  ```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nam4D9zGpHvdWaTCYHSL?p=preview, I used here *.state* and not *.when* for routing.

Comment: Thanks for your well thought out response. I took $resolve from an example I was following. I'll use a different name when I fix it. I'll be sure to mark this as my answer once I've had a chance to implement these changes.